# How to access method of "sub-model" in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

In Django, I have the following models.py

```
class Product(RandomPrimaryIdModel):
  feature1 = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
  feature2 = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
  feature3 = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)

class Mattress(Product):
  category_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  size = models.CharField(max_length=5)

  def category(self):
    return "bedding"
  category = property(category)
```

I have the following views.py file

```
def update(request, id):
  product = Product.objects.get(id=id)
  ...
```

In this method, update, can I call a method defined in the "Mattress" model from the Product model. For example, I want to write: if product.type == "mattress" where type has been defined in the Mattress Model and Mattress is a sub-model of Product.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example seems to sit between two different ways you can go, but is currently not correct. What is happening is that you are creating two tables: Product, and Mattress, and they are completely unrelated. Regardless of the fact that Mattress subclasses Product, it is just inheriting its structure. You cannot query anything in the Product table about a mattress because a mattress is in the Mattress table.

One way to go is to consider a Product just abstract, to be subclassed by actual products:

```
class Product(RandomPrimaryIdModel):
    class Meta:
        abstract=True
```

This will prevent a Product table from being created. Then you would directly query a mattress via: `Mattress.objects.filter()`

But this seems a bit limiting in terms of introducing many types of products, and having to manage different tables for them. The other way to go is to use a Product table, but use generic relations to support attaching any type of other table as a content object:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic

class Product(RandomPrimaryIdModel):

    feature1 = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    feature2 = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    feature3 = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

With this, you would be able to set the `content_object` to be a Mattress instance. You can then use the ContentType to query:

```
p_type = ContentType.objects.get(name="mattress")
Product.objects.filter(content_type=p_type)
```

Comment: You just get a Mattress instance and assign it to content_object. The model fills in the other fields for you. The content_object is not really a field in the db. Its a helper property that resolved the type and object id for you. Yes you would either need to create more models for other types. Or you need to think of a way to create a ProductDetails object that can store all data about all types of products. There has to be a table schema of some type. So you are either doing a table per product type or a generalized single table.

Comment: quick followup: the product model factored out fields that were common to all types of products (ex: title, condition, price). With the content type solution, how would one go about maintaining these factored out fields or would I need to specify them for each individual product type?

Comment: Doing it with a single table is probably the more manageable way because that means you can easily add products on the fly without creating new tables. But what that requires is a product table with a bunch of generic fields, and then another table that maps the generic fields to named fields of that product type. Then you need to have a setup where you create Proxy objects for each product that shows you the properties but under the hood is saving them back to the generic mapped ones.

Comment: Honestly, I have never done a product-based django site yet and if I did I would probably just use an existing shopping app framework for django

Comment: And to answer your follow up question, the Product table can still have all of those common fields for every product, and should. The specific product fields are only for the product-specific meta info

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a case of automatic down casting. I needed a similar approach for a shopping cart that held generic 'ProductBase' instances but I needed to access the children's specific functions which were the actual products of type ProductDownloadable, ProductShipped, etc.

Django does not natively support this, but one could code it through introspection or use [django-model-utils](https://github.com/carljm/django-model-utils/#inheritancemanager) and once that is installed you could do:

```
# return a list 'child' classes of Product - in your case Mattresses
mattress_list = Product.objects.all().select_subclasses() 

# return the direct 'child' class of Product - in your case Mattress class
mattress = Product.get_subclass(id=some_id) # returns the 'child' subclass
mattress.foo() # executes method on foo on Mattress class (not on Product class)
```